# Service Provider raising an error. The class it provides it's not found

Tags: php, laravel, service-provider

I'm trying to test a dummy component of my own with a Service Provider, but I'm getting this error:

> FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class
>   'Luismartin\Notificador\Notificador' not found

This is the **Notificador class**, located in *vendor/luismartin/notificador/src/Notificador.php*  (I ran a composer dump-autoload after creating it):

```
<?php
namespace Luismartin\Notificador;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;


class Notificador
{
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function notificar(User $usuario, $mensaje)
    {
        // notifier actions...
    }

}
```

Its **Service Provider**, placed in *app/Providers/NotificadorServiceProvider.php*:

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Luismartin\Notificador\Notificador;

class NotificadorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('Notificador', function() {
            return new Notificador(new Mailer());
        });
    }

}
```

It has been added in *config\app.php*:

```
'providers' => [
     //...,
     Luismartin\Notificador\Notificador::class,
],
```

And finally, the **controller** method in which I'm trying to use the Notificador component:

```
private function notificar($mensaje)
{
        $admin = User::where('name', 'admin')->first();

        $notificador = App::make('Notificador');

        $notificador->notificar($admin, $mensaje);
}
```

What else should I do?

I've also tried deleting composer.lock and running composer update. Here's what it displays at the end:

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Luismartin\Notificador\Notificador' not found in /home/vagrant/Code/helpdesk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository
PHP Stack trace.....
```

Comment: Delete your composer.lock file and run composer update again. Also ry changing location in the app.php file to `App/Providers/NotificadorServiceProvider::class` (do this before composer update)

Comment: How is this package being installed? Composer? If so, keep service provider in vendor folder with your other code.

Comment: I've deleted composer.lock and run composer update. It also displays an error related to my class. I've added it above.

Comment: @MikeBarwick I wrote my package directly in the vendor directory. I didn't use any remote location.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I confused the component class by the Service Provider class when declaring it in the providers list:

```
'providers' => [
     //...,
     App\Providers\NotificadorServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Now it works.